# rsyslog on CentOS 8.2

Tags: rsyslog, centos8

I just configured rsyslog 8.1911 on CentOS 8.2. The server rsyslog.conf has these lines

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/logs/serverlogs/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" 
*.* ?RemoteLogs
```

This works - i.e. new directories get created each day, logs get written etc. But the log entries for clients go into the rsyslog server's log files too. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Putting existing logs in an "if" condition and RemoteLogs in the else clause fixed it. The name of the log server is prod-log.So

```
if ($fromhost contains "prod-log") then {
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*      
# other existing files
} else {
*.* ?RemoteLogs
}
```

Ideally one ought to set up rules and use them. For now, this works.